# Correct wiring for 3 wire single phase motor

Tags: wiring, induction-motor, single-phase, 3-wire

I have a single phase 3 wires ( + ground ) submersible pump , I need to understand the correct wiring what type of motor is this and is the capacitor important ?  the previous owner was not using this capacitor.

nameplate info :

> MultiMotors System 
>   Model : 4H07M22/A 
>   Motor: 1~ 
>   KW 0.75   Hz 50 V 220 A 5.7 cosφ 0.98 min 2825 
>   C30µF/450V ( I assume this is the value of the capacitor to use )
>   CI B IP 58

and the diagram on the side of the pump is :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiB1pu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally for submercible pump the cap. is mounted outside in the control box (NOT IN THE WATER!), thats why probably that is missing..
the circuit diagram appears to be correct..generally electrolytic A.C.capacitors are used being smaller in size.buy one of the rating specified on the name plate and fix.
v t ingole

Comment: thanks ! actually i have tested it this morning with this connection and it's running, do you know what is this type of motors called ( I want to do some reading on this )

Comment: also my control box is just circuit breakers is there something else I should add ?

Comment: This is called split phase capacitor start/run single phase induction motor

Comment: It is called split phase capacitor start/run single phase induction motor. Generally for such rating an MCB should be adequate but it depends. vtingole